# Dot file in Python, attributes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dot

I got a couple of graphs in .dot file as well as their png image.
How can I use them in python keeping not only their labels and edges but also the attributes such as color of an arrow and shape of the node?

Till now i was using following method:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
import networkx as nx    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Gtmp = pgv.AGraph('test.dot')

W = nx.DiGraph(Gtmp)

nx.draw(W, with_labels = True) 
plt.show()
```

The sample dot file is presented below:

```
 digraph G { graph [ dpi = 300; splines=curved; ]; clusterl0e0e0 -> clusterl0e0A_i[arrowhead=none, color=black, weight=0.5] ;
 clusterl0e0S_ENCRYPTEDKAB_i[label=S_ENCRYPTEDKAB_i, shape=plaintext, color=none, fontsize=11, height=0.25];}
```

Comment: Does the `pgv.AGraph` line not load all of that?

Comment: I think `Gtmp` probably already has that information in it.  "How can I use them" is unfortunately too vague to give a better answer.  There might be lots of different things you're trying to do with them.  Can you tell us what your desired output is?

Comment: No as an output of my script i am getting the graph which contains directed graph but in one color the same is with the shape and color of nodes. I want to somehow differentiate the different colors edges and different shape nodes and print them on the screen or compare while i am comparing two graphs.